# How to increment and decrement value of a TextView?

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView. When I click on a button named "add to cart", my counter should get incremented. I have a remove button. When click on it, my TextView should be decremented.

Also, How to find the id of two different items in a ListViews?

Comment: paste your code.

Comment: Show your efforts.

Comment: get text from TextView, cvonvert text to number, increment number, convert number to text, set text to TextView. What's a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to cerate two sqlite database table first currentOrder and second one Orderhistory when you create order then it goes to current order and you can edit ,delete with id of first coloumn .